# Laravel validation rules: checking against input array index

Tags: laravel, validation

In my form the user can add (or remove) licence items which
are generated as input nested arrays:

```
<div>
    <select name="licences[0][type]">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="motorbike">Motorbike</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="licences[0][car_spec]"  value="">
    <input type="text" name="licences[0][motorbike_spec]"  value="">
</div>

<div>
    <select name="licences[1][type]">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="motorbike">Motorbike</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="licences[1][car_spec]"  value="">
    <input type="text" name="licences[1][motorbike_spec]"  value="">
</div>

...
```

and here are my rules:

```
$rules = [
    'licences.*.type' => 'required',
    'licences.*.car_spec' => 'required_if:licences.*.type|car',
    'licences.*.motorbike_spec' => 'required_if:licences.*.type|motorbike',
];
```

Now how can I ensure that the validations match the same index (*) of the licences array ?
For instance, the `licences[1][car_spec]` input is checked against the `licences[1][type]` input and not against the `licences[0][type]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this one:

```
public function validation(){
    $rules = [
        'licences.*.type' => 'required',
        'licences.*.car_spec' => 'required_if:licences.*.type|car',
        'licences.*.motorbike_spec' => 'required_if:licences.*.type|motorbike',
    ];
     foreach($this->request->get('licences') as $key => $value){
         $rules['licences.'.$key.'.type'] = 'required';
         $rules['licences.'.$key.'.car_spec'] = 'required_if:licences.*.type|car';
         $rules['licences.'.$key.'.motorbike_spec'] = 'required_if:licences.*.type|motorbike';
     }
    return $rules;
}
```

I hope this works for you.