# How to require array in Laravel validation and prevent getting unexpected keys

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to set require validation for array of objects in laravel and used following rule:

```php
[
    'translations.*.languageId' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::in(Language::all()->pluck('id'))],
    'translations.*.data.title' => 'required|string',
]
```

but there is problem when i send request without `translations` key the `validate` function does not throw require error for `translation` key.

so i add `translations` key separately too.

```php
[
    'translations' => ['required', 'array'],
    'translations.*.languageId' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::in(Language::all()->pluck('id'))],
    'translations.*.data.title' => 'required|string',
]
```

But there is a problem if an extra key is sent that should not be in the `translations` array (like `locale`), it can still be seen in the output of the `validate` function.

how can i prevent this unexpected result?

Comment: take a look here, does it solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114290/laravel-validation-rules-checking-against-input-array-index/66114507#66114507

Comment: @ZiaYamin sorry no.

Answer (score 0):

As taylorotwell answered [my issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36374) and close it there is no way to `validator`  do this filter.

> Filter the array to only have the items you actually want after validation.